# ubuntu touch core apps | database version mismatch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am not able to run Ubuntu touch core apps properly. It was running fine until I installed QT5 along with QT4. I tried removing all and installing ubuntu-sdk from scratch. But still no luck.

**Error**

```
Error: SQL: database version mismatch
[CLOCK] TimerPage loaded
QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: " " 
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
[CLOCK][ERROR] Error creating WorldClock table in db:Error:
```

When I run the app, header, divider is not shown and controls not shown on swiping from the bottom. background is not shown properly.

How do I solve this sql db version mismatch

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by deleting the database files from the file system. Of course you will lose all data you had inserted in the application.

You'll find the files to delete under directory:

```
~/.local/share/Qt Project/QtQmlViewer/QML/OfflineStorage/Databases
```

Check all the `*.ini` files until you find the one matching your application. Delete that one as well as its `.sqlite` counterpart. After that I could run my app again.